# returning a pointer to a derived class

Tags: c++

Class `A` contains a pointer to a derived class. I simply want to implement an accessor member function `get_ref()`, but I'm getting an E0120 error:

> return value type does not match the function type

and a C2440 error:

> 'return': cannot convert from 'A::B *' to 'B *'

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std; 

class B; 
class A
{
public: 
    B* get_ref();
private:  
    class B; 
    B* p; 
};

class A::B
{
public: 
    int num; 
};

B* A::get_ref()
{
    return p; 
}
```

Comment: There are no derived classes in the code you've shown

Comment: What is the `class A::B` syntax? First time seeing this. This shouldn't compile. Edit: ahh, nvm. Just saw that `B` is declared inside `A`.

Comment: Can either of you elaborate. I thought class A::B defines B as a derived class of A.

Comment: @user7348 No, that makes `A::B` a nested class, not derived.

Comment: "Derived class" has pretty specific meaning in context of programming, it's when you have inheritance like this: `class B: public A {};` - then class `B` is said to be derived from class `A`. What you wrote here is nested class, `B` is nested in `A`, but they have otherwise nothing in common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two `B` classes: `::B` and `A::B`. These are two totally unrelated classes. Your `A` class's `p` member is of type `A::B*`. Your `get_ref()` member function returns a `::B*`, a totally unrelated class, so no, you can't `return p`. Pick one, and drop the other:

```
class A {
private:  
    class B; 
public: 
    A::B* get_ref();

    B* p; 
};

class A::B {
public: 
    int num; 
};

A::B* A::get_ref() {
    return p; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the insights.  The code I was using here was a slight adjustment of some code from my book. Not surprisingly, it didn't work at all. I checked the index and I see that we haven't covered nested classes yet, and I just assumed this was a notation for a derived class. I'm independently studying, and my book has so far been excellent. The author has one sentence indicating that we are using a nested class which I didn't notice until now because of your insights. We'll cover nested classes later in the book. For now, I'll just copy the book's code for my program. Thanks!

Comment: @user7348 I would be curious to know which book you're reading, if you are willing to share.